# Expression: vector subscript out of range error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I have encountered vector subscript out of range error, but I could not figure out where the error is, there are 6 functions plus the main function. Some codes were omitted. Is there something I could watch out for when writing code to avoid this error?

Function 1

```
int matchInput(vector<string> fileRead, int index) {
    for (size_t i = index; i < fileRead.size(); i++) {
        if (fileRead[i].find(in) != string::npos) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Function 2

```
vector<string> grabReplies(vector<string> fileRead, int index) {

    vector<string> replies;

    for (size_t i = index + 1; i < fileRead.size(); i++) {
        while (fileRead[i].find(out) != string::npos) {
            replies.push_back(fileRead[i]);
        }
    }
    return replies;
}
```

Function 3

```
string pickReply(vector<string> replies) {
    string reply;

    int item = rand() % replies.size();

    return replies[item];
}
```

Function 4

```
vector<string> fileRead(string fileDir)
{
    vector<string> fileRead;            
    string line;                        

    ifstream rawFile(fileDir);          

    while (getline(rawFile, line)) {    
        fileRead.push_back(line);       
    }

    return fileRead;                    
}
```

Function 5

```
bool wordMatch(string userInput, vector<string> fileRead, int index)    
{
    string delimiter = " ";             
    vector<string> wordsUserInput;      
    vector<string> wordsOnFile;         
    string s;                           
    string token;                       

    s = userInput;                      

    size_t pos = 0;                     
    token = "";                         
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {     
        token = s.substr(0, pos);                           
        wordsUserInput.push_back(token);                    
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());               
    }

    s = fileRead[index];            //s set to on file record

    pos = 0;                        //reset position counter
    token = "";                         //reset token
    while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) {     
        token = s.substr(0, pos);                           
        wordsOnFile.push_back(token);                       
        s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());               
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < wordsUserInput.size(); i++) {    
        for (size_t j = 0; j < wordsOnFile.size(); j++) {
            if (wordsUserInput[i] == wordsOnFile[j]) {      
                return true;    
            }
        }
    }
    return false;               
}
```

Function 6

```
string sanitising(string dirty) {
    string clean;           
    clean = dirty.erase(0, 8);      
    return clean;           
}
```

Main function

```
int main() {

fileDir = "../src/reply.txt";                       
fileVector = fileRead(fileDir);

cout << "Welcome to the ChatBot" << endl            
     << "a program by 27023119"  << endl << endl
     << "Please ask me anything" << endl
     << "to end chat just enter quit"    << endl;

while(1)                                            
{
    index = 0;
    cout << ">";                                
    getline(cin, userInput);                    

    if (userInput == "quit"){                   
        cout << "Thanks for using Chat Bot!" << endl;   
        break;                                          
    }

    index = matchInput(fileVector, index);

    if (wordMatch(userInput, fileVector, index) == true) {
        replies = grabReplies(fileVector, index);
        reply = pickReply(replies);
        cout << sanitising(reply) << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Sorry I don't understand." << endl;
    }
}

return 0;                                           
}
```

Comment: can you give the backtrace?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: It's done in visual studio, which when encountering this error does not allow trace at all, should I try debugging it with g++? However, g++ will usually not give out error about vector sub-script

Comment: Which line is 1733?

Comment: line 1733 is a line in the visual studio vector file, not my code

Comment: Scroll down the callstack window until you find code that is yours.

Comment: My prime suspect is that you failed to open the input file, as this happens very often even with small programs, and it would lead to an access to the first element of an empty vector. Add some error handling. Verify that you have read the data you assume that you read.

Comment: The call stack has problem with `s = fileRead[index]; ` in function 5

Comment: What's the variable `in` in `matchInput`? Doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere in the code you posted nor being passed to the function which is being used at `fileRead[i].find(in)`

Comment: The `in` is used to match a string, and it's sitting in a .h file, like so `const string in = "<input>";`

Comment: @LeoWang *but I could not figure out where the error is* -- The Visual Studio debugger tells you exactly where the problem is.  Look at the call stack, go to the function *you* wrote, and look at `index`.  It is out-of-bounds of the number of entries the vector is sized to.   Why that is?  Well that's your job to look at your code and figure out why your vector is using an index that's out-of-bounds, i.e. debug your code.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it again